# hide/remove view from document flow if it has empty property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using backbone to create some nice model instances and populate some Views with them.

Example of model:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var userJon = new User({
    username:'jonraasch',
    displayName:'Jon Raasch',
    bio:'some nerd'
});
```

The problem I am facing is that not all the model instance will have all 3 properties. Some may miss on bio, others on displayName.

I would like to cut out the missing properties view entirely from being visible, when bio:'' or id doesn't contain bio at all. It I set `displayName` to `''`, there will be a placeholder in the document flow. I don't want empty placeholders.

Can this be done using backbone.js and how? I created a pen, to help visualise what I mean: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpwERv

Comment: is some sort of filtering like array [reduce](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJp6yYzt3SAhWKabwKHS2qCJwQFggWMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce&usg=AFQjCNG5y6qS8juF9mnkgIEZQgeRUeoJ3A&sig2=ES7aCYTGy4b0pRyz5wQLyw&bvm=bv.149760088,d.dGc) not enough? like filter it before you do your thing

Comment: I am not sure if I follow, but I am not using backbone to create and fold views on the fly. The html is already there. And as you can see, sometimes too much html is already setup. I use backbone just to represent the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your codepen, you can simply add the following:

```
if(!dn){ // <--- model value. Use _.isUndefined if 0 is valid
    this.remove();
}
```

This will remove the `el` element from DOM.

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBadwr)

---

I find it really strange that you have a view to display single attribute of a modal.

In most of the cases a view will display data in entire model. In such cases, if you want to avoid empty properties from being passed into whatever template method you're using, you can override the `toJSON()` method of your custom modal constructor to exclude empty values

Comment: thanks mate. I am just beginning to scratch the surface of backbone and JS overall, so no best practices in my code :)

Comment: @sanjihan Take a look at the top voted questions in [tag:backbone.js], the common problems you'll have are probably solved already. It'll help you understand the specifics of Backbone and how to do things the Backbone way.